# Django Url NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, regex, django, urlconf

I'm trying to create an url that has both the slug and the pk of a given model. However, I'm running into the NoReverseMatch error when I try this.

The url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Blah Blah
    url(r'^dashboard/(?P<slug>[-\w]+])-by-(?P<pk>\d+)/$', WebsiteTemplateView.as_view(), name="websitedetail"),
)
```

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'websitedetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 42, 'slug': u'when-you-talk-you-hardly-even-look-in-my-eyes'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+])-by-(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the excess square bracket in the `<slug>` named group:

```
url(r'^dashboard/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)-by-(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
                         WebsiteTemplateView.as_view(), name="websitedetail"),
```